# Disqus API detect deleted posts

Tags: api, disqus

Does anyone know how to detect deleted posts in using the Disqus API?

I'm syncrhonizing posts from Disqus using the `forums.listPosts` method of the API.

The `listPosts` method does not update the date of a deleted post, so when retrieving posts incrementaly using the `since` parameter, deleted posts are never retrieved again, thus I cannot delete them (They have an `isDeleted` attribute).

Any idea, besides brute force, on how to obtain deleted post when they're deleted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to sort data by the date it was modified, so there's no direct way to get comments that have been most recently deleted.

About the only option is to occasionally page through all the deleted comments on the site (by only using the "include=deleted" parameter) and update any comments that have changed states the last time they were added to your database.

Comment: Your answer confirms what I saw. So, you get the "green check". Unless someone else can prove us wrong. Thank you for your time answering :)